# Is there a convenient way to invert an Nd4j array elementwise?

Tags: java, nd4j

E.g. I have x = [1 , 2, 3]. I want y = 1/x = [1, 1/2, 1/3].

Ideally, I want a function that works the same way as the following line taken from the **nd4j documentation**, only for the multiplicative inverse instead of the hyperbolic tangent.

```
 INDArray tanh = Nd4j.getExecutioner().execAndReturn(new Tanh(myArr))
```

If there isn't such a function, is there a more efficient, or at least cleaner, way to do a custom elementwise operation on an array than using a for loop and inverting each value individually?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Pow` transform operation with `-1.0` as the exponent argument:

```
INDArray inv = Nd4j.getExecutioner().execAndReturn(new Pow(myArr, -1.0));
```